# Safari fails to display the window title of a dynamically created page

Tags: javascript, html, safari

I create an empty popup window to which I write html code, including a title tag. This has worked before on all browsers, but Safari 5 or 6 do not work.

The code (minimized example code):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Main Window Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>The main page opens a second window:</p>
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    myWindow = window.open();
    myWindow.focus();
    myWindow.document.write("<html><head><title>The Other Window Title<\/title><\/head><body><p>Some text<\/p><\/body><\/html>");
    myWindow.document.close();
</SCRIPT>
</body>
</html>
```

In Firefox this results in a main page titled "Main Window Title" and a second window titled "The Other Window Title".

But in Safari, the second window's title remains the generic "Untitled".

To me, the Safari behavior appears to be a bug, but I wonder if there is a way to make it work anyway?

(If I supply an url parameter to the `window.open`, where the url is a web page with a title tag, then it displays correctly, but I do of course not want that since I want it to be dynamically created.
I also tried inserting `myWindow.document.title = "A new title";` but it did not have any effect in Safari, (but it has in Firefox).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the url `about:blank`

Example:

```
var myWindow = window.open("about:blank")
```

Comment: Thanks! Simple working solution. The specification says "If no URL is specified, a new window with about:blank is opened", but newer versions of Safari obviousluy needs the explicit about:blank as the argument.

Comment: That is so bizarre that this is required. Thank you.

Comment: @Jason, this method no longer works in present versions of Safari, i.e version 9. But it did work in version 6. In version 9 of Safari, there will be no title, and even worse: an extra line below the title bar whose contents is the text "about:blank", and the size of this line is "stolen" from the window size, so now many windows are too small to fit the previous content!  Any other solution?